# Python: How to split and re-join first and last item in series of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series of strings, the series looks like;

```
Series
"1, 2, 6, 7, 6"
"1, 3, 7, 9, 9"
"1, 1, 3, 5, 6"
"1, 2, 7, 7, 8"
"1, 4, 6, 8, 9"
"1"
```

I want to remove all elements apart from the first and last, so the output would look like;

```
Series
"1, 6"
"1, 9"
"1, 6"
"1, 8"
"1, 9"
"1"
```

To use Split(), do I need to loop over each element in the series? I've tried this but can't get the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have a list of strings?

Comment: It's actually a column in a Dataframe but thought it easier to describe it as a series

Comment: Can you show how your data frame looks like? [edit] your question and add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split` and `rsplit` to get the various parts:

```
result = [f"{x.split(',', 1)[0]},{x.rsplit(',', 1)[1]}" if x.find(',') > 0 else x
          for x in strings]
```

If `strings` is a `pd.Series` object then you can convert it back to a series:

```
result = pd.Series(result, index=strings.index)
```

Comment: You can use slicing here right? Like `x[:3]+x[-1]`?

Comment: @Ch3steR Only for the example data of the OP.

Comment: How would you deal with a scenario where some elements are only 1 string? Currently this solution duplicates the single value. Thanks

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim What is the expected result in such a case?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim I'm surprised you say it duplicated the single value since it should've raised an `IndexError` instead. Can you please provide an example where it actually duplicated the value?

Comment: @a_guest Its a huge dataset, but it does this for every instance of a single string element. In the example above, the last element would show as "1, 1"

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim That's only possible if the original value was `"1, "`, i.e. only if it contained a comma. In your example however the original is just `"1"` but for that it must raise an `IndexError`. Can you please double check your input?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas vectorized `split` and then `apply` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["1, 2, 6, 7, 6",
               "1, 3, 7, 9, 9",
               "1, 1, 3, 5, 6",
               "1, 2, 7, 7, 8",
               "1, 4, 6, 8, 9",
               "1, 2, 6, 8, 8"])

s_split = s.str.split(',')

r = s_split.apply(lambda r:','.join([r[0], r[-1]]))
r
0    1, 6
1    1, 9
2    1, 6
3    1, 8
4    1, 9
5    1, 8
dtype: object
```

Comment: It's not efficient to split on every comma when you only need to first and last element of the split.

Comment: I believe `str` access is not vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
[i.split()[0]+i.split()[-1] for i in series.str.split('\n')].join('\n')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Use str.split series supports str conversion

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
 series.str.extract('^(\d+).*\D(\d+)$').agg(', '.join, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
 series.str.extract('^(\d+, ).*\D(\d+)$').sum(1)
```

Output:

```
0    1, 6
1    1, 9
2    1, 6
3    1, 8
4    1, 9
5    1, 8
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is failing to extract multiple digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything else then the string slice operator:

```
s[:3] + s[-1]
```

So given your (iterable) series:

```
refined_list = [ _[:3] + _[-1] for _ in series ]
```

Comment: What if he has multiple digit numbers?

Comment: fail of course. But there arent in the given series

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, it would probably be faster to just access the first and last index of the string.

```
input = pd.Series(["1, 2, 6, 7, 6",
               "1, 3, 7, 9, 9",
               "1, 1, 3, 5, 6",
               "1, 2, 7, 7, 8",
               "1, 4, 6, 8, 9",
               "1, 2, 6, 8, 8"])
```

Then:

```
for line in input:
    first, last = line[0], line[-1]
    print("first: " + first + " last: " + last)
```

**Output**:

```
first: 1 last: 6
first: 1 last: 9
first: 1 last: 6
first: 1 last: 8
first: 1 last: 9
first: 1 last: 8
```

Or you could try something like this if you want to reconstruct a new Series.

```
output = pd.Series()
for line in s:
    first, last = line[0], line[-1]
    output.at[len(output)] = first, last
```

**Output**:

```
0    1, 6
1    1, 9
2    1, 6
3    1, 8
4    1, 9
5    1, 8
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `your_series` series looks like that in your question:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> your_series = pd.Series(['1, 2, 6, 7, 6', '1, 3, 7, 9, 9', '1, 1, 3, 5, 6', '1, 2, 7, 7, 8', '1, 4, 6, 8, 9', '1, 2, 6, 8, 8'])
```

Then another option is to use the following one line solution with [`pandas.Series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
>>> s = your_series.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(x.split(',').__getitem__, [0, -1])))
>>> print(s)
0    1,  6
1    1,  9
2    1,  6
3    1,  8
4    1,  9
5    1,  8
```